# ayuda con un error en php "undefined index"

Tags: php5

Realicé un formulario y le puse botones para registar y consultar pero cuando yo aplasto los botones me vota el error `undefined index` generalmente en la linea 90,  101, 102 y 103 y no se como pueda arreglarlo agradecería su ayuda :(

```
           <form method="POST" action="opcionespersonal.php" >
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="ID">ID</label>
  <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" id="ID">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="nombre">NOMBRE</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="Nombre">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password">PASSWORD</label>
  <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" id="Password">
</div>

<center><input type="submit" value="Consultar" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn_consultar"></center>
<center><input type="submit" value="Registar" class="btn btn-success" name="btn_registrar"></center>
<center><input type="submit" value="Actualizar" class="btn btn-info" name="btn_actualizar"></center>
<center><input type="submit" value="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger" name="btn_eliminar"></center>
</form>
</center>

<?php
include("conexion.php");
$Id ="";
$Nombre="";
$Password="";

if(isset($_POST['btn_consultar']))
{
    $ID = $_POST['ID'];
    $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM personal where Id = '$Id'");
    while ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))
        {
    echo $consulta ['ID']."<br>";
    echo $consulta ['Nombre']."<br>"; 
        }
}

if (isset($_POST['btn_registrar']))
{
    $ID = $_POST['ID'];
    $Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];

    if ( $ID ==""|| $Nombre =="" || $Password ==""){
  echo "Los campos son obligatorios";
    }
    else
        {
  mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO personal (ID, Nombre, Password) values 
    ('$ID', '$Nombre', '$Password')");

        }
}
```

Este es el código amigos pero siempre me vota error

> undefined index en estas lineas $ID = $_POST['ID']; $ID = $_POST['ID'];
>           $Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
>           $Password = $_POST['Password'];

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, trata de que el código no lo pongas en imágenes, directamente pegalo en la pregunta en un bloque de código y así es mucho más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Todos los errores que tienes es por las variablen que llegan en `POST` ¿cómo las estás haciendo llegar ahí?

Comment: este es el inicio del codigo en php  <?php
 include("conexion.php");
  $Id ="";
  $Nombre="";
  $Password="";

Comment: Sí, amigo, pero sí nos planteas un problema, para poderte ayudar debemos revisar el código para llegar a una conclusión y en una es muy complicado revisarlo

Comment: Yo hice un formulario amigo en donde use los campos id nombre y password <form method="POST" action="opcionespersonal.php" >
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ID">ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" id="ID">
  </div>
asi son los demas input y de ahi le hice una conexion con la base de datos,luego procedi a programar cada boton

Comment: Listo, entonces pues copia el código, edita la pregunta pon el formulario, y el respectivo código php, también copiando el código  y pegandolo en la pregunta, al momento de editar hay unas ayudas a la derecha que te explican como hacer un bloque de código

Comment: ahorita lo hago amigo y muchas gracias por brindarme tu ayuda

Comment: Para eso estamos

Comment: ya puse el codigo amigo espero su ayuda

Comment: Ya ví el error, ya te lo respondo

Comment: muchisimas gracias yo he buscado pero no he dado con el error

Comment: Listo, amigo, revisa el código, alguna duda o sugerencia, me la comentas

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que cuando mandas un formulario por `post` o por `get` el para identificar los valores que enviaste lo hace por medio del `name` por lo tanto sí el `name` es así `name="password"` no puedes recibirlo en `php` cómo `$_POST["Password"]` ya que la "p" es mayúscula y `php` es sensible en las mayúsculas en el nombre de las variables, por lo tanto, debes dejarlos igual.

`HTML`

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="id">ID</label>
  <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="nombre">NOMBRE</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password">PASSWORD</label>
  <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" id="password">
</div>
```

`PHP`

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$Id ="";
$Nombre="";
$Password="";

if(isset($_POST['btn_consultar']))
{
    $ID = $_POST['id'];
    $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM personal where Id = '$Id'");
    while ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))
        {
    echo $consulta ['ID']."<br>";
    echo $consulta ['Nombre']."<br>"; 
        }
}

if (isset($_POST['btn_registrar']))
{
    $ID = $_POST['id'];
    $Nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $Password = $_POST['password'];

    if ( $ID ==""|| $Nombre =="" || $Password ==""){
  echo "Los campos son obligatorios";
    }
    else
        {
  mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO personal (ID, Nombre, Password) values 
    ('$ID', '$Nombre', '$Password')");

        }
}
```

Y listo, lo esencial siempre que vayas a ponerle un `id` y un `name` a un elemento, es llamarlos igual, para que no vaya a haber confusión de ningún tipo. Espero que te sirva, saludos!!

Comment: entonces la solucion seria agregar mayusculas en el name y en el id ya que las variables en php inician con mayuscula ?

Comment: Dejalo sí quieres como está en el ejemplo que te hice, sino, pues la idea es que queden igual el `name` y el nombre que llega por `$_POST[]`

Comment: Osea sí es `name="nombre"` entonces `$_POST["nombre"]` y así con los otros

Comment: amigo segui las sugerencias que me brindo el name y el post tienen el mismo nombre solo que al momento de aplastar los botones no realiza ninguna accion

Comment: ¿Cómo así? Explicame un poco